# Create a numeric navigation

Tags: menu, navigation, typo3, typoscript

How do I create a menu which automatecaly names the involved page into a numeric navigation?

This would be my page tree:

News

|--- Newsarticle tom (contains 9 content elements)

|--- Skeet's stuff (contains 9 content elements)

|--- Jessicas 5 articles (contains 4 content elements)

In the frontent all 3 pages will be simply displayed as a numeric navi:


(Imagin the 9 textpic elements of "Newsarticle tom" in here)

**1** - 2 - 3

Comment: Perhaps with a user function itemArrayProcFunc

Comment: Just to get updated: Are any of these answers working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**{register:count_HMENU_MENUOBJ}** should do the trick - I found it in the comments here http://www.typo3wizard.com/de/snippets/menus/nummeriertes-menue.html. (german)

Here I used @konsolenfreddies HMENU example, modified for your demands. (Untested).

```
temp.menu = HMENU
temp.menu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        noBlur = 1
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            altText = subtitle // title
            title = subtitle // title
        }
        CUR < .NO
        CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        ACT < .CUR
    }

    2 < .1
    2 {
        wrap = <ol>|</ol>
        NO {
            allWrap = <span>Nr.{register:count_HMENU_MENUOBJ}|</span>
            allWrap.insertData = 1
            ATagBeforeWrap = 1
            }
        CUR < .NO
        CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active"><span>|</span></li>
        ACT < .CUR
    }
}
```

In this case, I guess all subpages are taken in account when numbering. And the full setup as described on the site is far more complicated. But if you know your typoscript, you'll understand.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you could use the alternative navigation title to name them individually, but that might be tedious in a larger page tree.

a solution would be to create a OL navigation and remove the title via CSS. That way the navigation is still accessible and gives some hints about what's behind the numbers:

```
temp.menu = HMENU
temp.menu {
    1 = TMENU
    1 {

        noBlur = 1
        wrap = <ul>|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
            altText = subtitle // title
            title = subtitle // title
        }
        CUR < .NO
        CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        ACT < .CUR
    }

    2 < .1
    2 {
        wrap = <ol>|</ol>
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li><span>|</span></li>
        CUR < .NO
        CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active"><span>|</span></li>
        ACT < .CUR
    }
}
```

The corresponding CSS:

```
ol li span {display:none;}
```

Comment: Clever workaround. Take in account that in your solution, the numbers can not be clicked. However, with a little css magickery, it might work:
`ol li span {
  width:24px;
  margin-left: -20px; 
  padding-left: 20px;
overflow:hidden;
}` 
Unfortunately it's not valid. Source: http://forums.devshed.com/css-help-116/make-li-labels-clickable-in-an-ol-747500.html

Comment: PS: Alas, negative margins *are* valid indeed: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/

Answer (score 1):

**untested:**

You can override the link text via:

```
NO.stdWrap.cObject.10 = TEXT
NO.stdWrap.cObject.10.data = register:count_HMENU_MENUOBJ
# if the register starts with 0, add 1:
NO.stdWrap.cObject.10.stdWrap.wrap = |+1
NO.stdWrap.cObject.10.prioriCalc = int
```

Instead of the title, you should get now the number.

Relevant TSref: http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/9/#id2649360